# Access - Query to move dupes into one table and non-dupes into another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Goal:

A query that will create two tables. One holding the duplicates and one holding the none duplicate records.

How my current query works:

When my query is ran, the duplicates are identified and displayed in a column brought in from Table 2.

SQL query I have now:

```
SELECT
     Table1.Column3 , Table2.Column3
    ,Table1.Column4 , Table2.Column4
    ,Table1.Column5 , Table2.Column5
    ,Table1.Column7 , Table2.Column7
    ,Table1.Column8 , Table2.Column8

From      Table1 
Left Join Table2  
On

(        Table1.Column3 = Table2.Column3
 AND     Table1.Column4 = Table2.Column4
 AND     Table1.Column5 = Table2.Column5
 AND  (  Table1.Column7 = Table2.Column7
      OR Table1.Column8 = Table2.Column8
      )
 )
```

Is this possible? The purpose of this is to provide users the ability to run a duplicate check on a file, followed by exporting the table that has the  **non-duplicates** as a new file while they can look at the **duplicates** table for data analysis.

I am currently working on my query so I will update this post as I identify improvements.

Sample Data per request (Eliminated Column 5 in the data below):

```
Table1.Column3  Table1.Column4  Table1.Column7  Table2.Column7  Table1.Column8  Table2.Column8  
AAA             9898            7897897546                        9878795644        
BBB             9898            5489411321                        3321346544        
AAA             9898            8948798794                        3987496321        
AAA             9898            1321316564                        9874631245        
AAA             8878                                              A11111111111  A11111111111    
BBB             8878                                              A22222222222  A22222222222    
BBB             8878            33333333333     33333333333         
BBB             6988            44444444444     44444444444
```

What you are seeing above is the query identifying duplicates. The Table2 Columns are the duplicates that have been identified (Query is bringing in those two columns from Table2).

In this case, I would want the duplicates to be removed and stored in its own table and the non duplicates to be stored within another table (along with the Table2 columns that I brought in removed).

Also, with this query, Access doesn't allow me to select the Make Table function.

Comment: Would you please provide sample data and expected results to help us understand your question ?

Comment: Shouldn't have to export just to view records. One query cannot export to two tables. Run multiple actions.

Comment: @GMB Included more details and screenshots. Please ask anything so I can clarify further.

Comment: @June7 No, I am not exporting two tables. I am creating two tables. The exporting can be done manually.

Comment: Basically same comment. Why create tables when queries can display records? Should post code as text formatted like table instead of image.

Comment: @June7 Because the user is going to export the table...The exporting portion has nothing to do with the goal here.  I am trying to build a query based off the criteria mentioned above. I will replace the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query can be exported.

Try adding WHERE clause to query. You would need two queries.

Used the posted dataset as source table for query. Note I left period out of field names when creating table.

For duplicates seems simple:
`WHERE Table1Column8=[Table2Column8] OR Table1Column7=[Table2Column7]`

To select non-duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Table1Column3 & Table1Column4 
NOT IN (SELECT Table1Column3 & Table1Column4
    FROM Data WHERE Table1Column8=[Table2Column8] OR Table1Column7=[Table2Column7]);
```